# Umbraco quotation marks

Tags: html, xslt, umbraco

I have a problem when i try to print out my tinymce in umbraco with xslt
it renders just fine but it puts quotation marks around it.
Can anybody help with why?

[image: Image of code]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:Examine="urn:Examine" xmlns:ucomponents.cms="urn:ucomponents.cms" xmlns:ucomponents.dates="urn:ucomponents.dates" xmlns:ucomponents.email="urn:ucomponents.email" xmlns:ucomponents.io="urn:ucomponents.io" xmlns:ucomponents.media="urn:ucomponents.media" xmlns:ucomponents.members="urn:ucomponents.members" xmlns:ucomponents.nodes="urn:ucomponents.nodes" xmlns:ucomponents.random="urn:ucomponents.random" xmlns:ucomponents.request="urn:ucomponents.request" xmlns:ucomponents.search="urn:ucomponents.search" xmlns:ucomponents.strings="urn:ucomponents.strings" xmlns:ucomponents.urls="urn:ucomponents.urls" xmlns:ucomponents.xml="urn:ucomponents.xml" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets Examine ucomponents.cms ucomponents.dates ucomponents.email ucomponents.io ucomponents.media ucomponents.members ucomponents.nodes ucomponents.random ucomponents.request ucomponents.search ucomponents.strings ucomponents.urls ucomponents.xml ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/forsideBokse/widgets/*">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="./overskrift"/></h1>
<div><p><xsl:value-of select="./broed" /></p></div>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think it is putting quotes round it, that's just how your browser is showing the rendered value in its code view.

What is happening is that the XSLT is outputting the value as an encoded string instead of unencoded HTML. You need to add the attribute `disable-output-escaping="yes"` and the outer `p` tag:

```
<div><xsl:value-of select="./broed" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the a tag it disappears now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess that possibly the `data-mce-href` attribute is the cause. If possible, change this to a `href` attribute and try again.

Comment: Thanks now i works with the code you wrote, don't know why.
It didn't work yesterday, but today it works :D